# Queuing (property) animations with Qt

Tags: python, qt, animation, user-interface

**Context:**

I'm developing [an UI frontend for an autonomous car](https://github.com/halflings/robot-SVGMap) that will constantly send back its coordinates to the app.

I want the car to move subtly when it gets those coordinates instead of just teleporting, so I want the car's model to be updated immediately but the view to be slowly moved to the new coordinates.

I can already do that using QPropertyAnimation (with the car's position as a property) but only if I have many position changes I already know about. If I just launch an animation whenever the car's position is changed and the car's position changes in the middle of the animation the car's displacement will be immediately cut and the car will be teleported to the animation's end before moing to the new position.

**So ...**

All of that leads me to queue animations using Qt ! I can't find any container for that type of operation and don't want to reinvent the wheel, so how can I do that?
Also any ideas about a better way to do that are welcome !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `QSequentialAnimationGroup`, [docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsequentialanimationgroup.html#details).